# UIPageViewController Navigation Orientation works in iOS 5, but not 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a page turning app, that works properly in the iOS 5.1 simulator, but I'm updating to iOS 6 and am having an issue with the UIPageViewController.  All page viewcontrollers have a UIScrollView set to bounds added to them.  I have the navigationOrientation set to Horizontal and page turning works properly in in iOS 5.

```
BookController *bc = [[BookController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                                               navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                             options:nil];
bc.dataSource = bc;
bc.delegate = bc;
bc.bookDelegate = theDelegate;
```

In iOS 5 the following methods fire when scrolling horizontally...

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

**But, in iOS 6 they fire when scrolling horizontally and vertically.**

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what is going on is Apple added a scroll view or scroll gesture recognizer into the mix in iOS 6 because `UIPageViewController`s now support `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` whereas they did not prior to iOS 6. This might just be a change you will have to live with, but I will do a bit more searching around to see if there is some way to disable vertical scrolling.